# zip the values from a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in python 2.7 that has the following structure:

```
x = {
     '1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
     '2': ['d', 'e', 'f']
    }
```

The length of the value list is always the same and I would like to basically zip the value lists with corresponding values. So, in this case it will create three new lists as:

```
[['a', 'd'], ['b', 'e'], ['c', 'f']]
```

I know I can write an awful looking loop to do this but I was wondering if there is a more pythonic way to do this. I need to preserve the order.

Comment: How many keys do you have? Just the two (`'1'` and `'2'`)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
zip(*x.values())
```

Explanation:

- `x.values()` returns `[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]` *(order may change so you might need to sort `x` first.)*
- `zip([a, b], [c, d])` returns `[[a, c], [b, d]]`
- To expand `x.values()` into arguments to `zip`, prepend `*` to it.

Comment: That doesn't have a defined order. It may produce `[['a', 'd'], ...]` or `[['d', 'a'], ...]`.

Comment: @DanD. if you want it by key order: `zip(*list(zip(*sorted(x.items())))[1])`

Comment: While not the OP's question, there are cases where you want to avoid nested lists. For those, I suggest using `list(itertools.chain(*x.values()))` to flatten the returned list

Answer (score 2):

This is single line solves the problem but is likely worse looking than your loop. It loops over the sorted keys and produces a list to pass to zip and then maps over the result converting the tuples into lists.

```
>>> x = {'1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], '2': ['d', 'e', 'f']}
>>> map(list, zip(*[x[k] for k in sorted(x)]))
[['a', 'd'], ['b', 'e'], ['c', 'f']]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
res = list(zip(x['1'], x['2']))
res = list(map(list, res))
```

An explanation:

```
zip(x['1'], x['2'])
```

Creates a `zip` object that links up your pairs.

```
res = list(zip(x['1'], x['2']))
```

That `zip` object now become a list of tuples.

```
list(map(list, res))
```

For each element in `res` (each tuple), change the data structure from tuple to `list`, as you requested in your desired output above (`map` the `list` data type onto all elements in `res`). Then, convert that `map` object into a list to arrive at the final, desired result.

Comment: Any reason this doesn't work, those who downvoted? It literally gives the output OP showed above.

Comment: You had to hard-code the keys?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: See above for an explanation.